# How to print text in blank cells next to active cells using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, excel-2016

I have two sheets; SheetA and SheetB where I want to find a match between all parameter IDs in SheetA (Column B) and the corresponding parameter ID's in SheetB (Column A). If there is a match, then print corresponding parameter values from sheetB (Column E) into SheetA (Column C). This part works fine, but instead of leaving all cases where there is NO match (IsError) blank, I want a "NA" into the blank cell in SheetA - Column C next to all active cells in SheetA - Column B.

What to write into my code between If IsError(rowNumber) Then and Else?

---

```
Private Sub CommandButtona1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        
     iRow = 1
     eRow = 4000
    
        For I = iRow To eRow
           rowNb = Application.Match(Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A" & I), Worksheets("SheetA").Columns(2), 0)
        
            If IsError(rowNb) Then
            'How to write NA where IsError(rowNb) is True?

            Else
            Worksheets("SheetA").Range("C" & rowNb).Value = Worksheets("SheetB").Range("E" & I).Value
        End If
        Next I
          
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I see two options: before looping, write `NA` into all cells in SheetA, column C. Or after looping, go back over SheetA, column C, and write `NA` into all empty cells.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the code? If I go with option A were I want to loop through all active cells in SheetB, column B and replace corresponding cells in Column C with NA, how would you code that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Option A would be something like `Worksheets("SheetA").Range("C2:C1000").Value = "NA"` - write `NA` into the entire column. You may need to find the last row first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well on start set variables for worksheets like below

```
dim wb as workbook
dim wsA as worksheet, wsB as worksheet
set wb=thisworkbook
set wsA = wb.worksheets("SheetA") ' or set wsA = wb.worksheets(sheet1.name)
set wsB = wb.worksheets("SheetB") ' or set wsB = wb.worksheets(sheet2.name)
```

cheange `eRow = 4000` to `eRow=wsB.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row`

and then check condition `If IsError(rowNb) =true Then`

full code

```
Private Sub CommandButtona1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dim wb as workbook
dim wsA as worksheet, wsB as worksheet
set wb=thisworkbook
set wsA = wb.worksheets("SheetA") ' or set wsA = wb.worksheets(sheet1.name)
set wsB = wb.worksheets("SheetB") ' or set wsB = wb.worksheets(sheet2.name)

iRow = 1 ' if u have headers iRow should be 2
eRow=wsB.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row    
        
For I = iRow To eRow
    rowNb = Application.Match(wsB.Range("A" & I), wsA.Columns(2), 0)
        
    If IsError(rowNb)= true Then
    'How to write NA where IsError(rowNb) is True?
        wsA.Range("C" & rowNb)="n/a" ' "NA" etc
    Else
        wsA.Range("C" & rowNb).Value = wsB.Range("E" & I).Value
    End If
Next I
          
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

*// edited

```
Private Sub CommandButtona1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dim wb as workbook
dim wsA as worksheet, wsB as worksheet
dim wanted as string
dim findRng as range

set wb=thisworkbook
set wsA = wb.worksheets("SheetA") ' or set wsA = wb.worksheets(sheet1.name)
set wsB = wb.worksheets("SheetB") ' or set wsB = wb.worksheets(sheet2.name)

iRow = 1 ' if u have headers iRow should be 2
eRow=wsB.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row    
        
For I = iRow To eRow
    wanted =wsA.cells(i,2)
    
    set findRng = wsB.range("A:A").find(wanted, lookat:=xlpart)    
    If findRng is nothing Then
    'How to write NA where IsError(rowNb) is True?
        wsA.cells(i,3)="n/a" ' "NA" etc
    Else
        wsA.cells(i,3) = wsB.cells(findRng.row, 5)
    End If
Next I
          
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, Thank you for your answer. When I try the code, I get an error; Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch. I thought it was because a .value was missing wsA.Range("C" & rowNb).value="n/a" , but adding that to the code didn't fix it. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Thank you so much Tomasz for helping a newcomer within VBA -  it is much appreciated!